# How do I fix my function definition that causes this error with my embedded class/struct: could not deduce template argument for 'T'?

Tags: c++, list, class, data-structures, private-members

I implemented a linked-list called `Node` that had a function called `freeData` where it would perform a delete on the node given and any following nodes.

I wanted to implement it inside my own custom `list` class as a private member, but came up with this error in Visual Studio 2019:

> C2672 'freeData': no matching overloaded function found
>
> C2783 'void custom::freeData(list::Node*&): could not deduce template argument for 'T'

I don't know what to change for my `freeData` function header to accept a `Node*` as an argument. I pass the argument `pHead` in these functions: `~list()` and `clear()`.

The previous definition before embedding `freeData` into the `list` class was `void freeData(Node <T>* &pHead)`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace custom
{

   template <class T>
   class list
   {
   public:
      list() : numElements(0), pHead(NULL), pTail(NULL) { }
      ~list() { freeData(pHead); }

      void clear() { freeData(pHead); numElements = 0; pHead = NULL; pTail = NULL; }

   private:
      struct Node;
      Node* pHead;
      Node* pTail;
      int numElements;
   };

   template <class T>
   struct list <T> :: Node
   {
      Node() : pNext(NULL), pPrev(NULL) {}
      Node(const T& t) : data(t), pNext(NULL), pPrev(NULL) {}

      T data;      // data of type T
      Node* pNext; // pointer to next node
      Node* pPrev; // pointer to previous node
   };

   template <class T>
   void freeData(typename list <T>::Node*& pHead)
   {
   }

} // end of namespace

int main()
{
   custom::list <int> l1;
   l1.clear();

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`freedata()` is a free-standing function.  Unlike class methods, free-standing functions have to be declared before they can be used.  But, you can't forward-declare `freedata()` in this case since its argument depends on a type that needs to know what `freedata()` is.  Catch-22.

To fix that, you could break up the declarations and implementations of the `list` and `Node` class, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace custom
{

   template <class T>
   class list
   {
   public:
      list();
      ~list();

      void clear();

   private:
      struct Node
      {
         Node();
         Node(const T& t);

         T data;      // data of type T
         Node* pNext; // pointer to next node
         Node* pPrev; // pointer to previous node
      };

      Node* pHead;
      Node* pTail;
      int numElements;
   };

   template <class T>
   void freeData(typename list <T>::Node*& pHead)
   {
      ...
   }

   template <class T>
   list<T>::list() : numElements(0), pHead(NULL), pTail(NULL) { }

   template <class T>
   list<T>::~list() { freeData(pHead); }

   template <class T>
   void list<T>::clear() { freeData(pHead); numElements = 0; pHead = NULL; pTail = NULL; }

   template <class T>
   list<T>::Node::Node() : pNext(NULL), pPrev(NULL) {}

   template <class T>
   list<T>::Node::Node(const T& t) : data(t), pNext(NULL), pPrev(NULL) {}

} // end of namespace

int main()
{
   custom::list <int> l1;
   l1.clear();

   return 0;
}
```

But really, there is no reason for `freedata()` to be a free-standing function in this example.  It should be a member of the `list` class instead, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

namespace custom
{

   template <class T>
   class list
   {
   public:
      list() : numElements(0), pHead(NULL), pTail(NULL) { }
      ~list() { clear(); }

      void clear() { freeData(pHead); numElements = 0; pHead = NULL; pTail = NULL; }

   private:
      struct Node
      {
         Node() : pNext(NULL), pPrev(NULL) {}
         Node(const T& t) : data(t), pNext(NULL), pPrev(NULL) {}

         T data;      // data of type T
         Node* pNext; // pointer to next node
         Node* pPrev; // pointer to previous node
      };

      Node* pHead;
      Node* pTail;
      int numElements;

      static void freeData(Node*& pHead)
      {
         ...
      }
   };

} // end of namespace

int main()
{
   custom::list <int> l1;
   l1.clear();

   return 0;
}
```